# Explicit polymorphism in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Is any way to specify explicit polymorphism mapping in Grails?

I successfully tried to use hibernate annotation

```
  @Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
```

but to make it work I need to move parent class to `src/groovy` and lose all gorm features.

Comment: Any update on it? I also need to use Explicit Polymorphism